# How to add Tags to ViewPager fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have my `ViewPager` adapter set up with a tab layout to indicate the pages. My problem is I am trying to add a tag to these fragments inside the `ViewPager` so that I may access their pages like this

```
AccountFragment accountFragment = (AccountFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag();
        if (accountFragment != null) {
            accountFragment.notAuthenticatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            accountFragment.nestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

As you can see I cannot access the Views in the `ViewPager` fragment because I cannot put a Tag on these fragments.

Anyways this is my Adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return AccountFragment.create();
            case 1:
                return OrdersFragment.create();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                title = "Account";
                return title;
            case 1:
                title = "Orders";
                return title;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

> UPDATE

I've added

```
public OrdersFragment ordersFragment;
public AccountFragment accountFragment;
```

then for my ViewPagerAdapter getItem() I've changed it to

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                accountFragment = new AccountFragment();
            case 1:
                ordersFragment = new OrdersFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

but when I try to access the child fragments Views it still returns null

```
accountFragment.notAuthenticatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
accountFragment.nestedScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Why don't you just keep fields for them, and assign those when you create them? For example, `AccountFragment account;`, `OrdersFragment orders;`.

Comment: im not sure how to set it actually but this is how I create it   `public static AccountFragment create(){
        return new AccountFragment();
    }`

Comment: I mean, in the `Adapter`, add those two fields, then assign them in `getItem()` before you return? E.g., `account = AccountFragment.create();`, `return account;`.

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem of trying to set a Tag for the fragments

Comment: But the obviates the need for setting the tag, as you will no longer have to use `findFragmentByTag()`. `AccountFragment accountFragment = viewPagerAdapter.account;`. Or use getters, or whatever.

Comment: So I tried what you said but when I try to access the Views in the account fragment it gives my a null pointer exception. Am i suppose to use findViewbyId still? if so how?

Comment: There's not enough information to determine the cause of your issue.

Comment: I've updated it, please check it out!

Comment: Well, yeah, that's pretty much just what we discussed. I mean, we don't know the code in `AccountFragment`, or if those variables are set correctly, or where/when you're trying to access them, or exactly what's null, etc. If you've got everything in the `Fragment` correct, code-wise, but are trying to access those `View`s too early, the `Fragment`'s `View` might not even be created yet. Like, if you're doing all that at the same time that you're setting up the `ViewPager`.

Comment: So Im sure that my AccountFragments variables are all set correctly and I've tried accessing those views in my on Resume which is after my fragments onCreate but it still returns null

Comment: `onResume()` might still be too early. Add a delay, or maybe temporarily put an `OnClickListener` on something to try to access those `View`s well after it's come on-screen. If that doesn't work, then there's likely some issue with some other code not posted.

Comment: I gotta go. If you've found that you're just doing that too early, I'd suggest that you instead use the `Fragment`'s arguments, and let it set up its own `View`s when it has them ready. Also, directly accessing a `Fragment`'s internals like that generally isn't a great idea, and the current issue is a good example of why. You might consider making use of an interface, through which the `Fragment` could pull the data from `Activity` when it needs to. Or possibly a ViewModel setup, but that might be a little advanced. Lastly, if need any further assistance, you'll have to put together a [mcve].